# Python - Eu gostaria de alguns exemplos de uso de "APLICATION/LD+JSON"

Tags: python, json

Eu sempre trabalhei com REST para integrações, agora estou usando um sistema novo onde não posso usar apenas JSON puro, eles usam LD Json, e eu ainda não entendi bem esse conceito e estou com algumas dificuldades para implementar.

Por isso minha pergunta é meio vaga, pois eu ainda não sei exatamente o que devo procurar, não entendi como é feita a estrutura do Json, e como eu monto ela...
Nem como fica o Header agora.

Estou tentando entender a Biblioteca [PYLB](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/pyld) mas ta tenso...

Comment: Olá Critopher, já que você é novo aqui na comunidade, que tal realizar o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) de boas-vindas? Assim você irá conseguir orientação de como fazer perguntas que algum membro consiga te auxiliar de forma prática.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**JSON-LD**](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#embedding-json-ld-in-html-documents) nada mais é do que um JSON, obviamente as chaves dele seguem um formato especificado.

Geralmente ele é embarcado nas páginas HTML, algo como:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://json-ld.org/contexts/person.jsonld",
  "@id": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/John_Lennon",
  "name": "John Lennon",
  "born": "1940-10-09",
  "spouse": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cynthia_Lennon"
}
</script>
```

O `@context` indica o tipo de conteudo que deseja informar que contenha, geralmente ele é usado para auxiliar buscadores, bots e afins a entenderem o conteudo da página atual.

Claro que ele pode servir para mais do que isto, mas eu presumo que isso vá depender da sua necessidade, por exemplo se deseja definir um formato especifico para as suas RESTs, isto provavelmente irá vir a calhar bem, já que cada resposta terá que ter o formato seguindo exatamente o **"context"** definido.

O uso do JSON-LD é para isto mesmo, tornar de fácil leitura algum conteudo, já que irá seguir uma "norma" (um "context"). Supondo que irá usar em algum lugar especifico, o uso de *PyLD* até me parece opicional, já que entendendo a 'simplicidade' e o básico https://json-ld.org/spec/latest/json-ld/ dá até pra fazer na "mão" (com Django ou Flask, supondo que esteja desenvolvendo para WEB).

O *PyLD* é apenas para facilitar mesmo, ele não vai fazer todo o seu trabalho, como a parte HTTP do teu Rest, isto quem fará é você ou o framework que escolheu para desenvolver o REST, veja um exemplo com Flask (fiz neste FW porque é o que eu uso atualmente):

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

todos = {}

class Pessoa(Resource):
    def get(self, id):
        data = '...aqui viria a resposta do banco ...';

        return {
            "@context": "http://json-ld.org/contexts/person.jsonld",
            "@id": "http://site.com/pessoa/" + id,
            "name": data.name,
            "born": data.birth
        }

api.add_resource(Pessoa, '/pessoa/<string:id>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

---

Eu não sei dizer se é obrigatório usar o `content-type` como `application/ld+json` na resposta do HTTP, mas supondo que seja, então você pode definir o padrão no `default_config`

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['JSONIFY_MIMETYPE'] = 'application/ld+json'

api = Api(app)
```

Mas creio que isso é relativo, vai depender do "cliente" (software) que vai acessar o REST.

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado...

Comment: @CristopherGollmann deixei um exemplo em Flask bem humilde só para entender mais ou menos a proposta.